# How to use ref from parent component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component (parent) and a class component (child). My problem is that I can't make redirect links of the parent to a specific section in the child.

I have this function below who works fine in the child component but the references are unknown in the parent..

```
handleOnClick = (event) => {
    //.current is verification that element has rendered
    if (this.filmsContent.current) {
      this.filmsContent.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "nearest",
      });
    }
  };
```

and the reference to the target:

`<div ref={this.filmsContent} ></div>`

I would like to use this function in the parent component with onClick but with the references `this.filmsContent` of the child component and I don't know how to do that. Do you have an idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Because the child component is passing the ref to the `div` and the parent component also need the value of `ref.current` you should be forwarding the ref instead of creating it in the child component. See the [forwarding ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) section in react  docs.

Comment: Let me know if you were able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help @subashMahapatra , but I went another way after all.

Answer (score -1):

you can

`import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';`

after your export default...

```
const history = useHistory();
```

And in your handle function use:

`history.push('/path');`

Answer (score -1):

You could create a function in the parent that receives a function as parameter and send it like props to the child, something like this:

```
function Child(){
  const [fun, setFun] = useState(null);
  const parentFunction = (childFunction) =>{
     setFun(childFunction);
  }
}
```

and you send it to the child like this:

```
<Child parentFunction={parentFunction}/>
```

Now when you render the Child, in the ComponentDidMount function you can do this:

```
class Child extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.parentFunction(handleOnClick);
  }
}
```

Doint this you will set the variable fun equals to the function in your child, and when you want to use it in the parent component all you have to do is call `fun()`, for example:

```
<button onClick={fun}/>
```

or

```
const doSomething = () =>{
  fun();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thnak you for your help @PaulMiranda